# Windows Server 2008 R2 Migration

Tags: windows, service

I have two servers (Dell PowerEdge 300 and Dell PowerEdge 610).

Basically I have set up the Dell PowerEdge 300 as a Domain Controller with ADDS and DHCP Server and DNS Server running on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.

I now want to move to the Dell PowerEdge 610 with exactly the same settings, roles, features, Domain, IP Addresses etc.

I have tried to create a back up and restore the back up but this did not work as it kept stating that there are no back up files in the folder. I stored the back up on an external hard drive.

I then tried sysprep to create an image but when the server had to be restated it would just load Windows again normally.

Any help or assistance would be very much appreciated and grateful.

Comment: What is being attempted is an HIR "Hardware Independent Restore" of an image based backup.  A backup application capable of doing this is required.  We use Storage Craft however Backup Exec, Acronis, etc could also be used.  The exact steps will depend on the application used.  Based on the wording of the question it is very likely that consulting help will be required for the project to be successful.

Comment: Thank you Ed for your comment. I tried using Acronis yesterday but this did not seem to work. I selected C: Drive to be restored to C: Drive, F: drive to be restored to F: drive which was okay as Acronis allowed me to select these paths. However, Acronis did not allow me to select the MBR or something. The new server (Dell PowerEdge 610) has a C: Drive, and F: Drive which are local disks in Disk Management as well as the DVD Drive, but nothing else appears. Please can you let me know what I should try doing differently.

Comment: I not familiar enough w/ Acronis to provide step by step instructions and you would need to provide much more detail on what was done and what failed. My general suggestion is read the manual and get local consulting help.  This is not a trivial project since it sounds like this is the only server.

Comment: I have managed to add the second server to the Domain as a secondary Domain Controller which replicated Active Directory and Group Policy. It did not replicate my Shares for which I will do manually. However I'm getting some error in the Event Log about the DNS Server. I'll post the error tomorrow as I'm not at the server at the moment.

Comment: Also is it okay to use an IP Address range of 10.10.1.1 to 10.10.1.255 with a Subnet Mask of 255.255.0.0 or 255.0.0.0?

Comment: Please start a new question, setting up a new DC & migrating data is quite different than the original post.